# What is called when two pictures are combined

Tags: shooting-technique, camera-design, style, picture-samples, cars

Like say, for instance, I saw a picture of the front of a older and newer Toyota Supra like it was transforming and it was cut in half.

Comment: I think any image that is created from more than one photographic exposure can be called a [_montage_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomontage). But, if you are thinking of a specific technique or a specific effect, then there may be a better name for it.

Comment: Can you at least provide a link to an example? There are several different ways that multiple images may be combined to create a single image. Depending on how this is done, there are several different terms for it. Layering, focus stacking, stacking to reduce noise in dim astro photos, exposure fusion, montages, "multiple exposure" effects, etc. are just some of the many different ways multiple image sources can be used to create a single image.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of multiple photographs is a "[photomontage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomontage)". More generally, the process of combining visual elements from multiple sources to form a single image is called "[compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing)", and such an image may be called a "composite image" or simply a "composite".

Answer (score 0):

A combination of multiple images is known as a ["Photocollage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage).